# An algebra with an antisymmetric product that is not a Lie algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $F$ be a field and $A$ an $F$-algebra with an antisymmetric product $\cdot$. In other words, for all $v,w\in A$ we have
$$v\cdot w=-w\cdot v.$$
Examples of such algebraic object include all Lie algebras.

> **Question:** Is there an example that is *not* a Lie algebra?

The only thing this algebra could miss is the Jacobi identity:
$$u\cdot(v\cdot w)+v\cdot(w\cdot u)+w\cdot(u\cdot v)\neq 0,$$
for some $u,v,w\in A$.

Comment: Isn't the wedge product antisymmetric? Basically any exterior algebra on any vector space is an example of what you're asking

Comment: Pick any $F$-vector space $V$ and any $F$-linear map $f : V \to F$. Define a product $*$ on $V$ by $a * b = f\left(a\right) b - a f\left(b\right)$. This is antisymmetric but generally does not satisfy Jacobi.

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414: the wedge product is graded symmetric: it satisfies $ab = (-1)^{|a| |b|} ba$ where $a, b$ are homogeneous elements and $|a|, |b|$ denotes their degrees. An antisymmetric product needs to satisfy $ab = -ba$ all the time.

Answer (score 1):

For an explicit example, take the $3$-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra with basis $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ and products $e_1\cdot e_2=-e_2\cdot e_1=e_3$ and all other products zero. Now introduce in addition the products $e_1\cdot e_3=-e_3\cdot e_1=e_1$. Then the algebra product is still skew-symmetric, but does no longer satisfy the Jacobi identity: 
$$
(e_1\cdot e_2)\cdot e_3 + (e_2\cdot e_3)\cdot e_1 + (e_3\cdot e_1)\cdot e_2 =-e_3.
$$